Does the study of cognitive biases overlap with philosophy?
As this article notes,

Cognitive biases are systematic cognitive dispositions or inclinations in human thinking and reasoning that often do not comply with the tenets of logic, probability reasoning, and plausibility. These intuitive and subconscious tendencies are at the basis of human judgment, decision making, and the resulting behavior.

Given that the “tenets of logic, probability reasoning, and plausibility” are part of philosophy, should the study of cognitive biases be considered part of philosophy?

If not by de-biasing one's bias, how can the relative-subjective morphed onto the intersubjective where the lived lifeworld horizon is paired and constructed by the Husserlian noesis?...

@Syed Please link to the paper of Korteling and Toet, not to the general findings from ScienceDirect and its AI-generated definition. Did you read the paper?

@JoWehler The link just automatically went to the top of the page. The quoted section is not AI generated. I edited the link to the particular paper.

@Philomath indeed to fix the landscape objective horizon is extremely hard if not impossible, similarly in contemporary physics String theory due to the exact same problem out of the too many different landscapes, its creator Susskind recently publicly admitted its failure and the theory needs a re-start. The first step is perhaps to identify those biases after Husserlian transcendental reduction which can be debiased...

@DoubleKnot Ah, you are referring to this video? That seems like a paradigm shift. Very remarkable. But I don't think we need even go that far. Bracketing seems a good approach to the many interpretations of QM as well..

There isn't much overlap, but I think that they can inform each other:
Philosophers should heed the findings of psychology to ensure they are avoiding (or at least acknowledging) these biases.
Psychologists can leverage philosophy as a source of data to identify biases and also as a source of potential theories of error.

Yes, I think it is. If you are going to be presenting some idea that is the result of your conjectural thinking rather than empirical evidence, you want to be sure you have done both the job of thinking, and the job of presenting what you have thought. This is the sort of thing that Daniel Dennett, or Daniel Kahneman write about.
I think Kahneman in 'Thinking, fast and slow' (I have just had a quick thumb through my copy and I can't find it, so maybe it wasn't him), said that the word 'clearly' is a danger sign. When someone uses 'clearly' they often mean 'I am pretty sure this is right, and as long as no-one looks too closely, I can get away with it.' I hope no-one consciously uses it this way, but it tends to pop up when you have an awkward paragraph that you want to finish but you aren't happy with.
BTW: here is a link to the Cognative Bias Index. I am not sure this question needs it, but it is a wonderfully dense diagram.

Clearly, obviously, evidently -- self-evidently -- all of these words are attempts to win the argument by intimidation. We all know that.

Though clearly a subject of psychological studies, it can lead to philosophical questions such as: Can we be confident in the superiority of human rationality?
And: how much should we trust our own judgments when we are aware of our susceptibility to bias and error?
This is an important part in discussions on free will where it is claimed that:

Belief in free will may cause people to overemphasize the role played by personal choice and underestimate the influence of external factors on others’ actions — this is known as the ‘correspondence bias’.

It can be argued that the causal relationship here is reversed and it is exactly the prevalence of these biases that brought us the deeply felt conviction that we have free will in the first place.
Kahneman (who received a Nobel prize for his work on cognitive biases) wrote about the importance of his work outside psychology:

We published the article [on biases] in Science because we thought that the prevalence of systematic biases in intuitive assessments and predictions could possibly be of interest to scholars outside psychology. This interest, however, could not be taken for granted, as I learned in an encounter with a well-known American philosopher at a party in Jerusalem. Mutual friends had encouraged us to talk about the research that Amos and I were doing, but almost as soon as I began my story he turned away, saying, “I am not really interested in the psychology of stupidity.” (..) Whatever the reason, the article soon became a standard reference as an attack on the rational-agent model, and it spawned a large literature in cognitive science, philosophy, and psychology.


Cognitive bias is an umbrella to cover several specific biases that do overlap with philosophy. The most familiar is confirmation bias but there are others that have some overlap. There are 13 specific biases that are listed in this article:
https://www.verywellmind.com/cognitive-biases-distort-thinking-2794763
